# Getting progress updates (via AJAX) on a controller action without blocking

Tags: component, development, jsession

I have a controller with an action that accepts requests over AJAX, does some data manipulation, and returns some data:

```
function publicDirectoryAjaxSearch(){
    // Check the form token
    JSession::checkToken('get') or die('Invalid Token');

    // Don't show PHP errors in raw output
    ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');

    // Sort out the session status
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('getOrganisationsStatus', 'Searching...');

    // Get orgs
    $response = $this->doPublicDirectorySearch();

    // Get the document object.
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();

    // Set the MIME type for JSON output.
    $document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');

    // Change the suggested filename.
    JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="result.json"');

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

This method can take a while, so I'm using JSession to store a status variable `getOrganisationStatus` that can be periodically checked via AJAX to see how far the `$this->doPublicDirectorySearch()` method has gotten...

```
function doPublicDirectorySearch(){
    ...
    while($running)
         $session->set('getOrganisationsStatus', 'Fetched '.$handled."/".$totalResults." results.");
    ...
}
```

However, I'm having some issues. If I set the Joomla global config session handler to **Database** the `getOrganisationsStatus` session variable always seems to 'lag' 1 data request behind. For example (in prep for this example I cleared all existing sessions):

1. Make a data request via AJAX to `publicDirectoryAjaxSearch`
2. Set an interval to get the request status session variable over AJAX to `publicDirectorySearchStatus`
3. Data request still running. Session value changing as `$this->doPublicDirectorySearch()` works through data
4. Status call made from setInterval to `publicDirectorySearchStatus`. Returned session variable is empty (this step repeats over the interval)
5. `publicDirectoryAjaxSearch` data request completes. Method returns JSON object
6. Final status call made over AJAX from setInterval to `publicDirectorySearchStatus`. Returned data (the session variable) now shows the correct text as set in the data request method.

If I set the Joomla global config to use **None** as the session handler (i.e. PHP's built in file-based handler) then the script blocks (as [PHP locks the session file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174378/php-blocking-when-calling-the-same-file-concurrently) when a script accesses it, so the AJAX call to find out the status has to wait til the method updating the session variable finishes - defeating the point somewhat).

Where am I going wrong? How can I..

1. Make a call to get data (takes some time)
2. Make a separate call to get a session variable that's being manipulated over time by the first call

Answer (score 2):

All your page requests share the same user session. Thus, if you call several pages, in an asynchronic way, under the same session, you can be finding a **race condition**. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

As PHP is not multithreading, there's no locking mechanisms to avoid these cases.

The best solution is to avoid the condition: reorganize the main loop and move the control to the Ajax side. In this way, the browser calls an **initialization**, the **inner loop** as many times as necessary, and the **finalization**.

- You have the control so you can show the progress status
- If you have thousands of items to process you can define discrete batchs of items to process (instead of one by one)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, however I'm not sure how this applies to my scenario. I have 2 separate AJAX calls to different methods in a given class, both of which are responding (and not blocking). The issue is JSession values seem to be locked until the first call finishes. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think the case you are describing is caused by a race condition. At the end, Javascript is running several threads trying to get answers from PHP running a single user session (in a single thread).

Comment: Using PHP's APC caching mechanism I can make this work, just not with JSession. This makes me think it's not a race condition as it wouldn't work full stop otherwise...

Comment: PHP's APC works in memory, instead of any disk caching. Therefore, some way of serialization may be ocurring internally.